# Как заполнить string-array программно?

Tags: android, строки, jsoup, arraylist

Можно в Андроид студио заполнить файл string.xml программночерез ArrayList например или через массив?

Использую парсинг сайта с помощью библиотеку Jsoup. Не как не могу разобраться как заполнить string-array в файле string.xml, и есть ли такая возможность???

Comment: павильно писать **праграмна**

Comment: нельзя ничего записать в `strings.xml`. Таких ситуаций, где это нужно сделать быть не может.

Comment: Я использую БД для добавление в избранное пункта меню, соответственно нужно заполнить БД, строки для БД беру из стринга. Но зачастую информации очень много и нужно вручную постоянно заполнять стринг, проще было бы заполнить стринг автоматически с помощью парсинга сайта.

Comment: то есть вы хотите заполнять strings, а потом сразу оттуда заполнять БД? Зачем тогда strings вообще?

Comment: Для того чтобы информация сохранилось. Если напрямую заполнить БД с сайта, то не факт, что на сайте что-нибудь не изменится. Постоянно будет зависимость от сайта

Comment: @metalurgus: Очень просто: есть код, который читает из strings.xml, а ТС не может его адаптировать.

Comment: о боже мой, я вообще-то пошутил насчет **праграмна**, чтобы вы обратили внимание на то, как вы его написали. Неужели вы серьезно восприняли?

Comment: ))) и так и так ошибка будет, такого слова нет. Я подумал, может Вам так больше нравиться)) Хотя программно вроде есть такое слово

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не нужен промежуточный этап с записью данных в ресурсы приложения тем более, что это невозможно. Ресурсы встраиваются в приложение на этапе компиляции и менять их после формирования APK-файла невозможно (если не использовать совсем тру-ультра-хардкор ради тру-ультра-хардкора).

Если вы хотите заполнять БД из сети то, получив из сети данные сразу и пишите их в БД без записи ещё кудато. Так у вас приложение всегда будет иметь свежие данные и не надо их будет руками в приложение встраивать

---

В случае если есть вероятность проблем с сайтом и/или требуется иметь начальный набор данных, то можно, не долго думая, соорудить такой ужасный костыль:

1. Сохраните в файл html код сайта.
2. Положите этот файл в `assets`
3. При первом запуске приложения/отсутствия данных в БД/отсутствии данных из сети натравите JSOUP на этот файл и пишите результат в БД.

Comment: Скорей всего так и придется сделать.
Но зависимость от сайта, я думаю тоже не очень хорошая идея

Comment: @Artsait, я только что добавил вариант обхода этого. Но он не очень красив

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробую, может так и лучше

Answer (score 1):

Обычно string-array в xml заполняют, чтобы парсить в коллекцию и использовать, например - в адаптере. Мне трудно представить назначение подобного, но если такая необходимость появилась, вам следует пересмотреть архитектуру приложения.

Где-то в другом месте вы намудрили.

Comment: Код уже так замудрил, что сам черт не разберет))
Через стринг заполняю БД, Стринг в свою очередь хочу заполнить через парсинг сайта. Вручную заполнять очень много времени уходи.

Может я принцип БД не совсем понял. Если её заполнить,  как её затем в плеймаркете опубликовать??? Содержимое БД я так понимаю не генерируется вместе с приложением?

Comment: Думаю в плей маркет это не нужно публиковать!